# Memories in frames

Tags: personal-practice, vipassana, meditation-insight

I have a question regarding my insight meditation practice. When i practice and my mind becomes still then when memories pop up i see them in frames. When my mind is not stilled i see memories fluently, like in a movie.

Is it normal to see them in frame by frame when meditating? What does it mean that they are seen in frames. Is that because conditioned and compounded phenomena is build by component parts and thereby im seeing the impermance?

May all beings be happy, peaceful and free from mental and physical suffering.

Harshani

Comment: What does the frame around your memory look like? Like a picture frame? Or like an architectura/structural frame?

Comment: Im sorry, what?

Comment: In your mind, when you see these frames surrounding your memories, what do the frames look like?

Comment: I just see a picture of the memory and there is no frame. I think i used the wrong word maybe. When i say frame i mean "still picture". I see the memory in still picture and then another still picture. Its not fluently at all. You know like a movie on Television it consists of many independent still pictures.

Comment: Well then, seems like you are quite normal then :) Here is a link on how memory works in a fun video. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TUoJc0NPajQ

Comment: So when you see the memory of "2x2=4" I see it as a still image. A single picture or photo of the equation. Same with lots of my memories. I am picturing the book cover of a favorite book and it appears as a "still picture". I am remembering my car and it appears as a "still picture" as well.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Christopher:) Im still wondering about how this "still picture"-thing is relating to the nature of the mind. By the way - great video you gave me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What happens is

Sense door > Sense contact > Metal image > Contact with metal image > Recognise > Evaluate > Sensation > Proliferation of metal form > Mental contact > ...

So there is a chance that at some stage you start seeing things in quantum.

NB: This is my personal opinion any sense contact is followed by metal contact as physical creates a metal impression also.

As a final note. Don't get carried away by this as it will cause you to regress. Keep up your meditation.

Following is and alternative image from [Formations by Piya Tan](http://www.themindingcentre.org/dharmafarer/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/17.6-Khandha-4-Sankhara-piya.pdf). This also shows that thoughts are cycling in nature hence why you might see things in quantums or frames.

[image: 5 sencses and 6 sense bases]

Comment: Thank you for this explanation Suminda and the PDF file about how formations work in daily life and the warning about regressing. I value that a lot.

Comment: No worries. If you have any other question don't hesitate to ask.